# Why does a new MVC4 project come with a WebApi route mapped by default?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

A default MVC4 application will come with a `RouteConfig` class that looks something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My question is, why the `MapHttpRoute`?  This is setting up routing for the new WebApi functionality, but I didn't choose a WebApi project, just a normal MVC4 project.  Nothing in a normal MVC4 project seems to require WebApi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the Microsoft developers behind MVC and WebApi. The reason why we have route registrations for both technologies in the template is that we wanted to make it easier for you to get started adding a Web API controller to your project. Just like with MVC if there are no routes registered, then your `Controller` class is not going to work. By having those 2 routes we make the getting started experience a bit more developer-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Web API is a feature of ASP.NET MVC 4. It's part of the ASP.NET Webstack (of love ;) The idea behind this is that if you want use the HTTP strongly typed model for your RESTFUL services the support is out of the box. And should be the preferred way instead on handling RESTFUL requests with "regular" controllers.

When you select a Web API project template the MVC the only change is in the project files tree structure. But some of the references to dependencies of a regular MVC project stay there since Web API is part of MVC.

If the route registration for ASP.NET Web API bothers you, you could always remove it.

Comment: But surely not all websites are going to require a RESTful API?  Isn't it overkill to support it out of the box?